# Java / Tomcat and file descriptor limits?

Tags: java, tomcat, file-descriptor

Does Java have any synthetic upper limits on the amount of open files a given process can use? I have set the system wide open files limit at 20000 but am still receiving FD too many open files related errors within tomcat. I've verified that ulimit shows the correct limit of 20000 for the given user.

Basically, does any settings within Tomcat need to be modified?

Comment: Have you checked you don't DO use all those 20k handles because of a resource leak?

Comment: according to lsof only a 1000 open files for that user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears the tomcat process in question had not been restarted since the ulimit modifications. I didn't think a restart was necessary, but surprisingly a restart fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to configure the system-wide open file limit, but don’t forget that individual users also have limits. Are you on Linux?  See `/etc/security/limits.conf` to assign specific limits per-group, per-user, and default.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware and do configure per-user. I'm asking if any non-system limits exist...limits specific to tomcat or java?